# How to observe if a NSManagedObject is removed from managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data

I am removing the persistentStore from a persistentStoreCoordinator at some point in my application (and loading another store) and `reset` my managedObjectContext.
When I do that, according to the documentation, I also need to delete all references to  managedObjects that have been fetched:

> All the receiver's managed objects are “forgotten.” If you use this
>   method, you should 
>       ensure that you also discard references to any managed objects fetched using the receiver,
>       since they will be invalid afterwards.

I would like to avoid having to go through all my fetchedResultsControllers, caches, arrays that may contain managedObjects, detail views that also store an object, etc.

Instead I'd prefer to observe if the managed object's `isInserted` status changes. Something like

```
[myObject addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"isInserted"
              options:0
              context:nil];
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

So – how can I observe if a NSManagedObject is removed from managedObjectContext?

Comment: If there were such a notification, what would you do in response to it? You'd still have to go through all of your fetched results controllers, etc, and clean them out. Resetting a managed object context is a major shock to your data model, and everything that touches the model needs to respond somehow.

Comment: Well, I would get this notification on each controller that owns a managed object. So I wouldn't have to go through the controller hierarchy manually, but instead each controller could react independently. This seems much more reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that observing `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification` works pretty well in my case.
It is being called twice – the first time, when the old persistent store is removed, the second time when the new store is added.

I am still testing wether this solution proofs better for my case than the one suggested by Nicholas.

Answer (score 3):

Use `NSNotificationCenter` to observe the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` message, then examine the `deletedObjects` method of your `NSManagedObjectContext`.  See the documentation for details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/deletedObjects

Comment: `deletedObjects` is actually nil. However the notification contains the key `NSInvalidatedAllObjectsKey`, which makes sense, as the objects haven't been deleted but invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in notification or change you can observe that really does what you want. But it's easy to build your own. When you go through the process of removing a persistent store and resetting the context, post your own notification-- `@"MyAppCoreDataExploded"` or something. Observe this notification in any controller that uses managed objects. When you receive that notification, clean up any local references.